# How can I configure the Xcode Bots to use the iPhoneSimulator instead of iPhoneOS?

Tags: xcode, bots

How can I configure the Xcode Bots to use the iPhoneSimulator instead of iPhoneOS? I have tried many different ways including adding the CFBundleSupportedPlatforms and DTPlatformName in the Info.plist file but the bot is always building the app with iPhoneOS.

Answer (score 0):

iOS is the operating system which runs on the iPhone (and some other Apple devices) and the iOS simulator. You have invented two new names in your question: "iPhoneSimulator" and "iPhoneOS" and it's not clear what you are referring to.
If you mean "iOS Simulator" and "iPhone", you can select the one you want (or both) in the bot settings: in the testing tab select "Test project for iOS" and "Run tests on all simulators". This will run the tests on the simulators for the iOS you have selected in Xcode.